# Rotate text in visualforce PDF

Tags: visualforce

I want to display column headers vertically. In visual force page it is working fine, but when i used the same code in render as PDF, it is not working. I have tried it in different way like created  CSS for rotation and directly added code in VF page instead of creating CSS. How i can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you know you want it at a fixed size, the most reliable way will be to create a reasonably high resolution graphic of at least 150 ppi and closer to 225 for better printing (set it to display at the number of pixels you need for your page). The printer can use the extra resolution at print time since it should be embedded in the PDF by the generator. Then, insert the graphic into your page as part of a table or however you're choosing to format the page. I generally use tables for everything.

You're right in that the generator doesn't always fully respect CSS, even when it's done in-line. I've found that the latter most often occurs when a client wants lots of borders around rows of cells along with entire tables that are either nested or stacked.

CSS formatting also goes "wonky" on me whenever there's an error related to data coming from the bindings to the controller that may not be entirely obvious. Make certain you have a line with `<apex:messages />` located above the `<head>` tag on your page to see those error messages displayed.

Comment: Actually those column headers are not static. For every master record we are creating tables for related child records